# amplifier PAM8403 separated ground on the output..?

Tags: amplifier

Ok, this thing  PAM 8403 has separated gnd. out...for left and right.so how do I connect my headphones which have 1 ground for booth channels...?  I haven,t tried it yet but I don,t know if it will work if I connect the booth ground (from left/right out) together..should I put a coil or a resistans ( and how big..?) in between the out ground.....please help me !!

Comment: Hi Jarle, welcome to EE stackexchange. In order to help you further information is needed, moreover please try to write your question in a better English. Add a link to the datasheet of the device you are referring to and a schematic and/or a photo of your circuit.

Answer (score 3):

The [PAM8403](http://www.technobase.jp/eclib/OTHER/DATASHEET/pam8403.pdf) is a dual class-D audio amplifier with differential outputs. Each output channel has a positive terminal and a negative terminal. *There is no ground.*

No, it is not safe to connect any of these terminals together.

You can rewire your headphones to bring out the four speaker terminals separately.

Or you could use two output transformers, connecting the primaries to the chip, and then using a common ground connection on the secondaries.